# Series of Ionic / Firebase AngularFire2 Errors After Reinstalling NPM Packages

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, npm, angularfire2

Within an ionic app, all npm packages have been removed and reinstalled with npm install. Now running ionic serve displays about a dozen errors mostly related to firebase and angularfire2.

[image]

To debug,

1. I've uninstalled and reinstalled angularfire2 and firebase
2. I've double checked the tsconfig.json file which looks the same as before the error started
3. I've restarted the server

And yet, still nothing....

There are also some npm warnings related to unavailable peer dependencies which I'm attaching below and I'm not quite sure how to handle...

[image]

Here's the main app's package.json dependency list:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.4.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.4.4",
    "@angular/core": "^4.4.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.4.4",
    "@angular/http": "^4.4.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.4.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.4.4",
    "@ionic-native/app-availability": "^4.3.0",
    "@ionic-native/call-number": "^4.3.0",
    "@ionic-native/clipboard": "^4.3.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^4.3.0",
    "@ionic-native/device": "^4.3.0",
    "@ionic-native/facebook": "^4.3.0",
    "@ionic-native/geolocation": "^4.3.0",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^4.3.0",
    "@ionic-native/sms": "^4.3.0",
    "@ionic-native/social-sharing": "^4.3.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^4.3.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^4.3.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
    "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.1",
    "babel-code-frame": "^6.26.0",
    "call-number": "^1.0.1",
    "chalk": "^2.1.0",
    "cordova-android": "^6.3.0",
    "cordova-browser": "^5.0.0",
    "cordova-clipboard": "^1.1.0",
    "cordova-ios": "^4.5.1",
    "cordova-plugin-appavailability": "^0.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-compat": "^1.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-console": "^1.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^1.1.6",
    "cordova-plugin-facebook4": "^1.9.1",
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "^2.4.3",
    "cordova-plugin-queries-schemes": "^0.1.5",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^4.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.2.3",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.2",
    "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": "^5.2.0",
    "cordova-sms-plugin": "^0.1.11",
    "debug": "^3.1.0",
    "es6-promise-plugin": "^4.1.1",
    "firebase": "^4.5.0",
    "ionic-angular": "^3.7.1",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "^2.2.1",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "ios-sim": "^6.1.2",
    "json5": "^0.5.1",
    "minimatch": "^3.0.4",
    "promise-polyfill": "6.0.2",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.3",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.18"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^4.4.3",
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.0.0",
    "install": "^0.10.1",
    "npm": "^5.5.0",
    "typescript": "^2.5.3"
},
"peerDependencies": {},
```

Comment: Can you run `npm uninstall` of the angularfire2 and firebase dependencies then install it back with `npm install angularfire2 firebase --save`?

Comment: Maybe that was unclear but this has already been done... Did it again though and similar results. There are a bunch of warnings required for peer dependencies though...

Comment: Did you get a different set of errors? Peer dependencies error instead of firebase or angularfire2 errors?

Comment: @alltej the typescript errors I'm seeing before are by going through localhost whereas the npm warnings are in the terminal when I do any sort of npm command such as npm install. The npm errors were there before as well. Just added a screenshot of the VScode terminal...

Comment: can you share the dependencies section of the package.json? the errors/warnings displayed are with `ionic-angular@3.7.1`. Did you update to this version recently?

Comment: Yes sure, just did that in the question body.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155942/discussion-between-david-haddad-and-alltej).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With angularfire2 version 5.0.0+, the `FirebaseListObservable` and `FirebaseObjectObservable` is deprecated. Please revert back to the 4.0.0.+ versions

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after troubleshooting this with the help of @alltej it looks like I was not careful enough with npm update command leading the AngularFire2 and Firebase npm packages to both be upgraded to versions with a major version number change leading to some breaking changes.

For example, FirebaseObjectObservable which was being used throughout the app is has been deprecated in version 5. Rolling back to a previous version solved the issue/